# Table type required for balloon plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph

I tried to make a balloon plot in R with my data using the `xtabs` and `table` functions but `ggballoonplot()` keep giving me this error.

[image: see image for details]

Is there a particular type of table that I have to use or is there another way to make a balloon plot that gets around this error?

Comment: Use a data.frame not a table

Comment: @dww Alright, I tired converting it using as.data.frame() but then I got an error for not being able to find the scale_fill_viridis_c() function and it does not plot anything. I am not good at R so I just mainly copy and paste code. What should I use instead of scale_fill_viridis_c()?

Comment: @dww All good mate, used scale_fill_continuous() and it made a plot I am satisfied with

Comment: `ggplot` operates on data frames, not tables. The viridis scales might not be in older versions of `ggplot2`. Check what version you're using.

Comment: @camille No worries now, got that fixed as well, just needed to install the  viridis library